# Jasmine unit test to check the scope of an Angular Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of items. When you click on an item, it brings up a modal to display data for that item. In the controller for the list, there's a function, openRecentsModal, that takes the data object from the ng-repeat list, and creates it on a new scope when the function is run. The new modal then has that object available as $scope.recentsFoldersData. I need to write a unit test to ensure recentsFolderData is defined on the scope, but everything I've tried results in "expected undefined to be defined." I'm hoping somebody can help.

Here's the method in the list controller to open a modal:

```
function openRecentsModal(obj) {
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  scope.recentsFoldersData = obj;
  var controller = 'recentsFoldersDetailController';
  $modal.open({
    scope: scope,
    controller: controller,
    templateUrl: 'js/modal/recents/folder/recentsFoldersDetail.tpl.html'
  });
}
```

Here's the modal's controller:

```
angular.module('modal.recents.folder', [])
    .controller('recentsFoldersDetailController', recentsFoldersDetailController);

  recentsFoldersDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
  function recentsFoldersDetailController($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.close = function close() {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('close');
    };
  }
```

Finally, here's the unit tests I'm working on (I've excluded the ones that are passing, as well as the helper functions that aren't needed for this test):

```
describe('recents folders modal controller tests', function() {
  var scope, q, modal, mockDetailController, mockListController, mockRecentService, mockFolderService, mockModalInstance, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('mainApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $q, $controller, $modal, _recentService_, _folderService_, $injector) {
    q = $q;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    modal = $modal;
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $httpBackend.whenGET('js/modal/recents/folder/recentsFoldersDetail.tpl.html').respond(200, '');
    mockRecentService = _recentService_;
    mockFolderService = _folderService_;
    mockModalInstance = {
      dismiss: jasmine.createSpy('modalInstance.dismiss')
    };

    mockDetailController = function() {

      return $controller('recentsFoldersDetailController', {
        '$scope': scope,
        '$modalInstance': mockModalInstance
      });
    };

    mockListController = function() {

      return $controller('recentsListFoldersController', {
        '$scope': scope,
        '$modal': modal,
        'recentService': mockRecentService,
        'folderService': mockFolderService
      });
    };
  }));

  describe('scope tests', function() {

    it('should place the data on the scope when openRecentsModal is called', function() {
      var obj = defaultSuccessfulRecentsDataResponse();
      mockListController();
      spyOn(scope, 'openRecentsModal');

      scope.openRecentsModal(obj);
      expect(scope.openRecentsModal).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);
      mockDetailController();
      expect(scope.recentsFoldersData).toBeDefined();
    });

  });

  /* helper functions */
  function defaultSuccessfulRecentsDataResponse() {
    return {
      id: 'id 1',
      name: 'first name',
      description: 'first description'
    };
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with a simple change to the function calling the modal

```
    function openRecentsModal(obj) {
      $rootScope.recentsFoldersData = obj;
      var controller = 'recentsFoldersDetailController';
      $modal.open({
        //scope: scope,
        controller: controller,
        templateUrl: 'js/modal/recents/folder/recentsFoldersDetail.tpl.html'
      });
    }
```

By allowing the object to be placed on $rootScope (UI-Bootstrap modal's default setting), rather than a new $scope, the test came back with a defined value

```
it('should put recents object on the scope', function() {
  mockListController();

  scope.openRecentsModal(defaultSuccessfulRecentsDataResponse());
  mockDetailController();
  expect(scope.recentsFoldersData).toBeDefined();
});
```